# Variable in "field from calculation"

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have a problem with performing binary operations with two variables. The operation executes successfully, but after refreshing the dashboard, it disappears because a new variable is created. Is there any way to bypass this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89qWG.png)
after that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOsAL.png)

Its my Query A:
my query A:

```
from(bucket: "search_jmeter_new_api") |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop) |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "avg" or r["_field"] == "count" or r["_field"] == "error" or r["_field"] == "max" or r["_field"] == "min") |> filter(fn: (r) => r["symbol"] == "TOTAL") |> filter(fn: (r) =>  r["number"] == "2.171.0_B_466_2024-03-06") |> group() |> sort(columns: ["_time"], desc: true) |> pivot(rowKey:["number","_measurement"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value")
```

Query B:

```
from(bucket: "search_jmeter_new_api") |> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop) |> filter(fn: (r) => r["_field"] == "avg" or r["_field"] == "count" or r["_field"] == "error" or r["_field"] == "max" or r["_field"] == "min") |> filter(fn: (r) => r["symbol"] == "TOTAL") |> filter(fn: (r) =>  r["number"] == "2.171.0_B_466_2024-03-06") |> group() |> sort(columns: ["_time"], desc: true) |> pivot(rowKey:["number","_measurement"], columnKey: ["_field"], valueColumn: "_value") |> rename(columns: {count: "count_2", min: "min_2", max: "max_2", avg: "avg_2", error: "error_2"})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynAJP.png)

I updated from grafana 7.5.10 and it was working but now i have 9.4.7
its photo from 7.5.10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXefD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHs2X.png)

Im trying to make binary operation with two veriables i tried some things like regex, filter by name, group by etc. every time when i set count_1 - count_2 and refresh dasboard tis disapear

Comment: case was so simple - 
|> range(start: v.timeRangeStart, stop: v.timeRangeStop)
change to: 
|> range(start: 2021-03-29T22:00:00Z, stop: 2030-03-29T22:00:00Z)
after that grafana interpreted this like static veriable and dont reset dashboard anymore